# Write periodic sequence of numbers with trigonometric functions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, modular-arithmetic, periodic-functions

Is there a way to generate formula using trigonometric functions from periodic sequences? One example is sequence [A153130](https://oeis.org/A153130) and formula discovered by Leonid Bedratyuk:
$$a\left(n\right)=\ -\frac{\cos\left(\pi\cdot n\right)}{2}-3\cdot\cos\left(\pi\cdot\frac{n}{3}\right)-3^{\frac{1}{2}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi\cdot n}{3}\right)+\frac{9}{2}$$

Is there general principles to write down such equations?

Comment: the formula was derived from the  generating function of the sequence $a(n).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the recurrence relation
$$a_n=a_{n-k}$$
i.e. periodic with period $k$ then the general solution is of the form
$$a_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}C_j \exp{\left(\frac{2j\pi ni}{k}\right)}$$
For some constants $\{C_0,C_1,\dots C_{k-1}\}\subset\mathbb{C}$ which depend on the initial terms (this follows from the characteristic equation $r^k=1$). This can be rewritten in terms of trigonometric functions by using Euler's identity
$$a_n=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}C_j \left(\cos{\left(\frac{2j\pi n}{k}\right)}+i\sin{\left(\frac{2j\pi n}{k}\right)}\right)$$
It may be the case that the terms simplify somewhat to give formulas such as those given by Leonid. One could simplify the resulting formula using some trigonometric identities on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Where I can found book about such things, I mean characteristics of equation  r^k=1?

Comment: @NikaTvildiani There is some theory on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) under the 'Solving' tab.